# Tcpdf - Enable Scrolling

Tags: php, pdf, adobe, tcpdf, adobe-reader

Is there any class in tcpdf that make Page Display -> Enable Scrolling default options (When i open it in adobe reader), please help, i lost half of day on this. I found this class, but not what I need.

```
// set pdf viewer preferences
$pdf->setViewerPreferences($preferences);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was looking for the same answer and your question actually put me on the right track.

From inspecting the TCPDF class, ended up finding the answer in the TCPDF_STATIC class, in the static method TCPDF_STATIC::getPageLayoutMode().

The correct function to use would be TCPDF::SetDisplayMode($zoom, $layout, $mode). For your purpose I'd suggest:

```
$pdf->SetDisplayMode('default','OneColumn');
OR
$pdf->SetDisplayMode('default','continuous'); // continuous not documented, although should work.
```

Possible values for those parameters are as follows (from the method's PHPdoc):

- $zoom
  The zoom to use. It can be one of the following string values or a number indicating the zooming factor to use.

  - fullpage: displays the entire page on screen
  - fullwidth: uses maximum width of window
  - real: uses real size (equivalent to 100% zoom)
  - default: uses viewer default mode
- $layout
  The page layout. Possible values are:

  - SinglePage Display one page at a time
  - OneColumn Display the pages in one column
  - TwoColumnLeft Display the pages in two columns, with odd-numbered pages on the left
  - TwoColumnRight Display the pages in two columns, with odd-numbered pages on the right
  - TwoPageLeft (PDF 1.5) Display the pages two at a time, with odd-numbered pages on the left
  - TwoPageRight (PDF 1.5) Display the pages two at a time, with odd-numbered pages on the right
- $mode
  A name object specifying how the document should be displayed when opened:

  - UseNone Neither document outline nor thumbnail images visible
  - UseOutlines Document outline visible
  - UseThumbs Thumbnail images visible
  - FullScreen Full-screen mode, with no menu bar, window controls, or any other window visible
  - UseOC (PDF 1.5) Optional content group panel visible
  - UseAttachments (PDF 1.6) Attachments panel visible

```
    public function SetDisplayMode($zoom, $layout='SinglePage', $mode='UseNone') {
        if (($zoom == 'fullpage') OR ($zoom == 'fullwidth') OR ($zoom == 'real') OR ($zoom == 'default') OR (!is_string($zoom))) {
            $this->ZoomMode = $zoom;
        } else {
            $this->Error('Incorrect zoom display mode: '.$zoom);
        }
        $this->LayoutMode = TCPDF_STATIC::getPageLayoutMode($layout);
        $this->PageMode = TCPDF_STATIC::getPageMode($mode);
    }
```